# React / Redux - mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm pulling data in my action from a mongo api. I can console.log the data in the action but I can't get it to map to the components props. I just see an empty array. I'm new to react and redux so it's probably something simple I'm misunderstanding. Aside from my question and other links to good reads about this you would recommend would be amazing :) Thanks a ton guys!

***StoreLoader Component***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import storeData from '../data/storeData'

import { loadStoresFromServer } from '../actions'


class StoreLoader extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(loadStoresFromServer())
        console.log(this.props.data)
    }


    loadStores() {
        return (   
            <div className="row loaderContainer">
                {
                    storeData.map( item => {

                        return(
                            <div key={item.store} className="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 cardContainer">
                                <div className="card">
                                    <div className="card-block">
                                        <h3 className="card-title"> { item.store } </h3>
                                        <p className="card-text"> { item.storeName } </p>
                                        <p className="card-text"> Open Date: { item.openDate } </p>
                                        <div className="cardStatus">
                                            Status
                                            <div className="statusCircle circleFill"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <a className="btn btn-outline-secondary viewBtn">View</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }


    render() {
        return(
                <div>
                    <div className="loaderContainer">
                        <h3 className="loaderTitle">Ready For IT
                        </h3>
                        { this.loadStores() }
                    </div>


                    <div className="loaderContainer">
                        <h3 className="loaderTitle">Under Construction</h3>
                        { this.loadStores() }
                    </div>


                    <div className="loaderContainer">
                        <h3 className="loaderTitle">Upcoming Stores</h3>
                        { this.loadStores() }
                    </div>

                </div>

        )
    }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
         return { data: state.stores }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(StoreLoader)
```

***My Actions Index***

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const SET_STORES = 'SET_STORES'
export const LOAD_STORES = 'LOAD_STORES'



export function setStores(items) {
    return {
        type: SET_STORES,
        items
    }
}

export function loadStoresFromServer() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        const ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:3001/api/stores'
        axios.get(ROOT_URL)
            .then( res => {
                //console.log(res.data)
                dispatch(setStores(res.data))
            })
    }
}
```

***My Reducers Index***

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { SET_STORES, LOAD_STORES } from '../actions'


const rootReducer = combineReducers({ 
    stores
})


function stores(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SET_STORES:
            return action.items
        case LOAD_STORES:
            return {...state, data: action.items }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default rootReducer
```

Comment: Is the `console.log(this.props.data)` in `componentWillMount` what is giving you an empty array here?  If that's the case it's likely because `loadStoresFromServer()` is async, and you are trying to print the result before it gets back from the server.

Comment: I'm face palming so hard right now.... thanks!

Comment: It winds up happening more often than I'd like to admit.  It's always handy to have Redux Devtools or Redux Logger installed so you can look at the state and get notifications as it updates rather than counting on timing your logs right.  They are very, very helpful.

Comment: I'll try those out then. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your rootReducer your action case

```
case SET_STORES:
    return action.items
```

Does not set anything on top of the state. It is returning your action's data, but it is not adding to the redux state tree.

You will need that SET_STORE case to function like this

```
case SET_STORES:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        items: action.items
    })
```

Comment: It's the LOAD_STORES case so it's doing, the SET_STORES I can remove. That was from something else I was trying. Thanks! 

    case LOAD_STORES:
       return {...state, data: action.items }

Comment: is your problem resolved @SirFry ? if so, please select this reply as your correct answer. Otherwise people might try to find a solution for a problem which is resolved

Comment: It is but it was resolved by  DillGromble the guy who commented below the post.